# Swift substring crash on reversed (Need a Reason)

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, swift-subscript

I stuck  facing a strange issue with the following code:

```
var testString = """
This is test \r\n Pass        Fail
"""

if let charIndex = testString.range(of: "\n")?.lowerBound {
    let substring = testString[charIndex...]
    print(substring.reversed())
    var revereseString = String(substring.reversed())
}
```

My Application crashed with the following error: **Fatal error: Out of bounds: index < startIndex**

**Can anybody Explain why it is crashing in specific case**. If I remove "\r" from the string it will not crash. There are multiple way to fix the issue but I want to know why it is crashing?

Comment: I don't have an exact answer for this but `\r\n` is a paragraph break in the same way `\r` and `\n` individually are paragraph breaks. So maybe the crash is caused by the `range` function is both treating `\r\n` as a single character at one point and as two individual characters at another.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: That definitely causes the problem, but I wonder if the behavior  is “intentional” or a bug.

Comment: The Swift Programming Language book does not include \r\n when it lists [escaped special characters](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html)  but older documentation, referring to NSString, does include it. I also found it interesting that doing `count` on \r\n gives a length of 1 but when using `character(at:)` I can do it for `0` and `1`, so it looks like it differs between when the string is accessed as a String object or individual character. Maybe not relevant but interesting :)

Answer (score 2):

Its because `Swift` treats `\r\n` as one character,

```
let foo = "\r"
foo.count // 1
let fee = "\n"
fee.count // 1
let bee = "\r\n"
bee.count // 1
```

One of your solutions is putting a space between them `\r \n` and that would make it run because now they're 2 different characters.

**How ?**

The buffer registered them in the variable as one character yet treated in the `.range` iterator as two characters which causes the crash.

Comment: Thanks you @Mohmmad for providing the explanation. I like the explanation and might be the reason for crash.